# Prevent custom input in f.text_field with datetimepicker (Rails 3.2, Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

In my app there is a form for picking a date and time. I'm using Bootstrap and a jQuery datetimepicker to create a datetime string with a format that looks like `07/30/2014 10:00PM`.

I need to be able to transform this string into a time object and manipulate it at various places in the app. However, since the form is a `text_field` the users can put their cursor in the field and type any custom date they want, which is causing problems for when I need to convert the string to a time object.

Is there a way for me to prevent this on the front end, such as making it so you can't put your cursor in the bar and type a date, but have to use the actual picker function?

Form code:

```
= f.text_field :when_datetime, class: "form-control datetimepicker job-new-when-specific", data: {validatable: "1", error: 'Please choose a time.', empty: ''}, style: "width: 80%;"
```

Comment: Try adding `disabled: true` at the end. However you can never get around having some input validation server side.

Comment: For some reason `disabled: true` isn't doing anything. I can still put my cursor in the box. Made another dummy `text_field` with `disabled:true` and it works there....not sure what's going on

Comment: Could be some javascript interfering with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jQuery to set the date text field to read only, so values in these fields can be added by datetime picker

here is the code:

```
$("#textfield_id").attr('readOnly', 'true');
```

Comment: Here's what I'm running into: when I add an id to the `f.text_field` it breaks for some reason. It is blank instead of showing the default time and if I click on the calendar button I get this RunTime error: "This should basically never happen." So I also tried selecting it by the class (`$(".form-control datetimepicker job-new-when-specific").attr('readOnly', 'true');`) but that didn't seem to do anything I can still type any text I want in the box

Comment: @sixty4bit this is incorrect you are not calling it by its class you are put all the classes, I think you should just write the following  `($(".datetimepicker").attr('readOnly', 'true');)` besides you should be able to add ID normally could you please show me how do you add ID to your `text_field`

Comment: Thank you. `$(".job-new-when-specific").attr('readOnly', 'true');` seems to be working. Do you know if there's a way to do this that prevents the 'circle with line through it' symbol from appearing? And, if possible, that keeps the `text_field` from being grey?

Comment: @sixty4bit if the answer is correct please accept it. for changing the grey color, you can force background color `<input type="text" name="t1" placeholder="New" style="background-color:white">` Or even add the readONly to the html instead of he jQuery `<input type="text" name="t1" readOnly="true" placeholder="Newwwwwwwwww" style="background-color:white">` and you shouldn't be getting any red circle if it is readonly not disabled. what browser do you use

Comment: Thanks. I will make a new Bootstrap question about keeping that little symbol from appearing